# How would you know if ... is H-bond or permanent dipole or induced dipole?

Tags: intermolecular-forces, hydrogen-bond

For example like HCl, why isn't it a hydrogen bond?

Answer (score 2):

Hydrogen bonding is defined as an electrostatic attraction between a hydrogen atom bearing a partial positive charge in a molecule and an electronegative element of another molecule. The partial positive charge is the result of a dipole, caused by an electronegative element, *such as* F, O, or N. The other electronegative element to which the partially positive hydrogen is attracted to is also *usually* F, O, or N.

Here's the IUPAC definition; note that it does *not* exclude the possibility of hydrogen bonding in molecules such as HCl:

> A form of association between an electronegative atom and a hydrogen
>   atom attached to a second, relatively electronegative atom. It is best
>   considered as an electrostatic interaction, heightened by the small
>   size of hydrogen, which permits proximity of the interacting dipoles
>   or charges. Both electronegative atoms are usually (but not
>   necessarily) from the first row of the Periodic Table, i.e. N, O or F.
>   Hydrogen bonds may be inter-molecular or intramolecular.

http://goldbook.iupac.org/H02899.html

Comment: Can you answer me one last question....why is hydrogen bonding stronger than permanent dipole and not permanent dipole stronger than h-bond.....tell me all reasons...need it :)

Comment: Is this a homework question?

Comment: No Sir my homework question was list 3 intermolecular attractive forces and list them in order of increasing strenght? that ive answered it...but teacher might ask question beside that to see some knowledge..

Comment: Chemistry Speech in class 60s to answer the question and the remaining if time left then he would ask some question of what you know of this question so im trying to sum it up.

Comment: Try giving some reasons in your OP and I'll see if they're right.

Comment: ok umm...H-bond has high boiling point,great polarity of bond, and close approach of dipoles.

Comment: highly polar ecuase of 0, N, F

Comment: if those are true i dont know how to say it properly...or if anything else is missing ill add thanks

Comment: So am i kinda wrong?...cuz im going to bed if you please.